# Сохранение данных в БД пользователя и гостя при создании поста

Tags: php, база-данных

Гостевая книга на сайте где можно оставить пост как гостю так и зарег. пользователю.
Есть таблица post и user.

**Как правильно сделать:**

1) тоже сохранять данные (имя, email, url) зарегистрированного пользователя в таблицу post как и не зарегистрированного?

2) сохранять только id зарегистрированного пользователя в таблицу post и подгружать данные при выводе постов?

Comment: Всех пользователей писать в таблицу пользователей, в том числе не зарегистрированных. ввести признак того какой пользователь или использовать в качестве признака одно из полей, которые могут быть только у регистрированного. В таблице постов держать только id пользователя

Comment: А повторяющиеся имена незарегистрированных пользователей в постах нужно пресекать? 
Например - я Viktor25 добавил пост №1 а кто то другой подписался тоже  Viktor25  и под моим постом оставил свой пос №2

Comment: Вот и скажете второму Виктору, что такой ник уже используется, пусть придумает другой

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию!

Comment: Я бы не стал делать акцент на именах незарегистрированных пользователей. Допустим я подпишусь просто "Сергей", а Сергеев может быть много. Гостевая книга это не форум, где так важна уникальность имени. Можно просто обозначать что пост добавил "Гость" под именем "Сергей", а уже зарегистрированных проверять на уникальность